# how to show a percentage as coulmn in oracle database

Tags: oracle

Hi have a query with some column so now my question is ..how to show value and percentage of a column

```
for example:

Name   value     percentage

A       15000      20%
B       20000      15%
C       25000       4%
```

how to show like this...

Comment: Percentage out of what?

Comment: Is there some kind of aggregation calculation involved or is this just number formatting ("0.1" becomes "10%")?

Comment: What are your expectation? any input and output example?

Comment: for example let u consider that am having a 1235 as a value so my need is to calculate another column as percentage of that column like (1235) is a 25% like this i want to show...

Comment: How is 25,000 a smaller percentage then 15,000?

Comment: Please read [this blog post by Stack Overflow's #1 answerer](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for advice on how to communicate your questions more effectively. Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the per cent sign only, just do it:

```
select Name,
       Value,
       Percentage || '%' as Percentage
  from MyTable
```

If you want to compute the percentage, say on Name field, you can do it with analytical functions

```
select Name,
       Value,
       Round((sum(Value) over (partition by Name) / sum(Value) over ())*100) || '%' as Percentage
  from MyTable
```